# Study sound design in Germany

Tags: sound-design

Hello,

Can you recommend me the best education /courses/ for sound design in Germany? Could you tell me any universities which offer this kind of education?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way i see it udk only offers a master course for something like sound design, the bachelor is more to become a ¨tonmeister¨. But there are several other institutions like of course Babelsberg  http://www.hff-potsdam.de/de/studium/ba-studiengaenge/sound.html 
Ludwigsburg http://www.filmakademie.de/studium/studiengang-filmmusik-sounddesign/filmtonsounddesign/
and Trossingen http://www.mh-trossingen.de/studium/musikdesign.html

for all these study programms you have to have knowledge of musicology/compositon/music history (solfedge, rythmicdictee, sight score reading/writing)

If you`re not a half composer or you don`t want to deal with music writing during your studies your quite lost in germany.

But you should check out the courses of your dutch neighbors.
Utrecht/Hilversum http://www.hku.nl/web/Studiekeuze/Muziek/SoundDesign.htm
Amsterdam http://www.ahk.nl/filmacademie/opleidingen/sound-design/

You will have to learn dutch, quite doable for german natives, and you would have to pay studyfee, for which you can get a credit.

If you would get BAFög in Germany, you will get even more when you study abroad ;-)

I am studying at NFTA/Amsterdam and i find it splendid.
So if you have any further questions feel free to ask!

p.s.: Dont even look at the Musiccube Bonn

Answer (score 0):

find Carl-Frank Westermann. http://www.udk-berlin.de/sites/soundstudies/content/index_ger.html